# when cookies is deleted manually from browser then logout from laravel would be mismatch token

Tags: laravel, cookies, csrf

When the user logs in on the page, then deletes the authentication cookie manually from the browser and finally trying to logout, then the logout won't be possible because of  mismatch token. How to handle this?

Tried to handle the mismatch token using exception handling but it doesn't work

```
php artisan make:auth
```

To logout I have used a post form and sending the CSRF token with it.

Comment: Create a validation in auth middleware to check for token exist else redirect to login?